# Debian Testing freezing because of overheating, fan sensors give confusing info

Tags: debian, sensors, fan

I'm running Debian Testing on a Dell Latitude 7480.

I've been having a lot of freezing issues, and I have finally narrowed it down to an overheating problem. On battery, I can work for 1hr+ with no problem, and sometimes the system will freeze: mouse stops moving, the backlight of the keyboard doesn't power off, I cannot SSH into this machine. On AC power the same occurs after 15-20 minutes after plugging in to power; the bottom of the laptop is quite warm when this happens (not scalding hot, just warmer than it should be). I am currently at this machine on AC and it hasn't frozen after 21 minutes, but I have a USB fan connected to it.

The problem is that the fan never starts. I ran `watch sensors` during the whole session yesterday and the temperature does vary; however, the fan speed always changes to a positive number during a watch cycle (2 seconds) and goes back to zero after one or two; so the system reads a spinning fan for about 2-4 seconds, then it stops, but I never hear it. I know the fan works because I ran the onboard diagnostic tool and the fan not only started but I could hear it at full speed at some point during the memory test.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that at some point I ran `sensors-detect`, which suggested I added the modules `fan` and `coretemp` to `/etc/modules`, which I did. When I run `lsmod`, both modules always display 0 on the `Used by` column.

Yesterday the system froze at 20:15, so today I checked `/var/log/syslog` and I found this:

```
Mar  9 20:15:01 host CRON[1203]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

I searched for this and all I got was [this post](https://www.unix.com/linux/110432-system-getting-crashed.html), but I cannot see it has any relation to my problem (I do have Apache installed but this is not a server, it's a laptop, and I don't run mysql here; also, the CPU meters don't go up, and reboot is not slower than it usually is). There are many other lines like this, but I cannot recall all of them having happened when the system froze; I'm sure not all of them did, because there are more log lines after some of them that indicate the machine was still running.

The only other information I can gather is the following, also from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: dell_smm-isa-0000
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: Adapter: ISA adapter
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: Processor Fan:    0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 6600 RPM)
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: CPU:            +39.0°C
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: Ambient:        +24.0°C
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: SODIMM:         +23.0°C
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: Other:          +24.0°C
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: nvme-pci-3c00
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: Adapter: PCI adapter
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: Composite:    +23.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +84.8°C)
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]:                        (crit = +89.8°C)
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: acpitz-acpi-0
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: Adapter: ACPI interface
Mar 10 18:45:20 host sensors[600]: temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[608]: Settings for hwmon6/pwm1:
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[608]:   Depends on hwmon6/temp1_input
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[608]:   Controls hwmon6/fan1_input
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[608]:   MINTEMP=20
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[608]:   MAXTEMP=60
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[608]:   MINSTART=150
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[608]:   MINSTOP=100
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[608]:   MINPWM=0
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[608]:   MAXPWM=255
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[608]:   AVERAGE=1
Mar 10 18:45:20 host systemd[1]: Started fan speed regulator.


Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]: Common settings:
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]:   INTERVAL=10
Mar 10 18:45:20 host ModemManager[795]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.18.6) starting in system bus...
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]: Settings for hwmon6/pwm1:
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]:   Depends on hwmon6/temp1_input
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]:   Controls hwmon6/fan1_input
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]:   MINTEMP=20
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]:   MAXTEMP=60
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]:   MINSTART=150
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]:   MINSTOP=100
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]:   MINPWM=0
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]:   MAXPWM=255
Mar 10 18:45:20 host fancontrol[787]:   AVERAGE=1
```

The two blocks above are not consecutive, but it is the relevant information. Here are the contents of some files I deemed relevant:

```
cat /sys/devices/platform/dell_smm_hwmon/driver_override 
(null)

cat /sys/devices/platform/dell_smm_hwmon/uevent 
DRIVER=dell_smm_hwmon
MODALIAS=platform:dell_smm_hwmon

cat fancontrol
# Configuration file generated by pwmconfig, changes will be lost
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=hwmon6=devices/platform/dell_smm_hwmon
DEVNAME=hwmon6=dell_smm
FCTEMPS=hwmon6/pwm1=hwmon6/temp1_input
FCFANS= hwmon6/pwm1=hwmon6/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon6/pwm1=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon6/pwm1=60
MINSTART=hwmon6/pwm1=150
MINSTOP=hwmon6/pwm1=100
```

The last one is already on the syslog block above, but I reproduce it here nonetheless.

All solutions I've encountered to no fan on Linux suggest I install `fancontrol` and then run `pwmconfig`. The first time I tried I got an error telling me there was no `/etc/fancontrol.conf` file; I tried running this command while a USB fan was plugged and it worked. To be on the safe side, I just pressed Enter to generate the config file with the default parameters, but I still cannot hear the fans kicking in. As I said above, the `sensors` program tells me the speed changes every 2-4 seconds, but the fan is never audible and it doesn't stay on. The fan works on Windows (this laptop used to have it but I replaced the SSD with a new one, but kept and didn't format the old one), and as I said above, also in the onboard diagnostic tool. I've also run a Puppy Linux on a USB stick and it doesn't have this problem, although I didn't hear the fan working either.

Is there a way to properly configure `fancontrol` to solve this? Are there any other options? I can very well use the laptop with a fan plugged in, but that's not the sort of solution I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case was to set modify `/etc/default/grub` so as to contain this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi=!Windows 2020"`. The `acpi_osi` parameter tells the kernel to treat ACPI events as if they were happening on the value OS.